# Is possible to define a bash script to run interactively by default?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, interactive

I have written some scripts and stored them in my `~/bin` folder. I'm already able to run them just by calling their title during a shell session. However, they aren't running interactively (I mean, my `~/.bashrc` aliases are not loaded).

Is there a way to mark them to run interactively by default? Or must I `source ~/.bashrc` inside of them to use any aliases defined there?

Other alternatives are welcome!

Comment: Do you want to make them run "interactively" or do you want them to load `~/.bashrc` by default? Because interactive shells come with some surprises, like ignoring `SIGTERM`

Comment: By now, I'm actually just looking for a way to use `bashrc`'s aliases in the scripts even when call them through bin reference

Comment: Consider changing your aliases into shell functions. Unlike aliases, functions are available when the shell is noninteractive. Functions aren't particularly more complex than aliases to write. `alias hw='echo hello world'` vs `hw() { echo hello world; }`

Comment: Well, I've tested here, but without use [`-i` flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/569447/364080), `bashrc` functions are not loaded just like its aliases

Comment: @ArthurHenriqueDellaFraga then you better `shopt -s expand_aliases; . ~/.bashrc` at the beginning of your script (~as in the non-accepted answer). You still have to modify a script to change its shebang, and as I already said, the `interactive` mode comes with some changes in behaviour which are not desirable in a shell script. And, as @kojiro said, better use functions instead of aliases. Aliases only have advantages when used in an _real_ interactive shell, I cannot think of any reason to use them in a script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all tips, I'll keep improving my strategy and learning about all UNIX environment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add the `-i` option to your hashbang(s) it will specify that the script runs in interactive mode.

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

Alternatively you could call the scripts with that option:

```
bash -i /path/to/script.sh
```

Answer (score 8):

Sourcing your `.bashrc` is not a good idea. You could create a `.bash_alias` file with your alias and then source that file in your script and use `shopt`

something like:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bash_alias
```

Bash man page states:

> Aliases  are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless
>   the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the descrip‐
>          tion of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).